# Django simple-history + taggit - track "Tags" field changes

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

Currently I am having a problem with storing history of tag addition/modification/deletion with the simple-history package

Everything is working as expected, except for the fact that the "tags" field changes are not represented in the history changes. Trying to check any other instance in history shows the same tags everywhere, no matter when they were added or deleted - they are always there.

```
class Task(models.Model):

<... some fields ...>
tags = TaggableManager()


history = HistoricalRecords(inherit=True)
```

Tried something like

```
register(taggit.models.Tag)
```

But to no avail.

I am stuck with the documentation for at least an hour or two and I'm, to be honest, really inexperienced with Python and Django in general. How can I make the history for tags work for me?